# setWindowOpacity not working for a child widget

Tags: qt

I've used `QPropertyAnimation` to change the opacity of a QWidget within a specific duration, let's say a QLabel. However I found that once I give a QWidget a parent, `setWindowOpacity` doesn't work for it.

By the way, should I call `QLabel::show` first or `QPropertyAnimation::start` first?

```
MainWindow w;

// code worked as expected
QLabel label;
label.setFixedSize(100, 100);
label.setStyleSheet("background-color: red");
label.setWindowOpacity(0);

QPropertyAnimation animation(&label, "windowOpacity");
animation.setDuration(2000);
animation.setStartValue(0.1);
animation.setEndValue(1.0);
label.show();
animation.start();

// windowOpaicty of label is always 1.0
QLabel label(&w);
// same code with QPropertyAnimation
w.show();
animation.start();

// windowOpaicty of label is always 1.0
MainWindow w;
QLabel label(&w);
label.setFixedSize(100, 100);
label.setStyleSheet("background-color: red");
label.setWindowOpacity(0);
w.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Looks like `windowOpacity` property is available only for widgets without parent which means "window" widgets. For any widgets inside "window" widget `windowOpacity` could be unavailable (at least on Windows OS).
2. Try to avoid using both **qss** and any style property (like "opacity"). Sometimes style properties and **qss** conflict with each other.
3. Opacity of widget can be implemented with **qss** only. If you subclass your `QLabel` and add custom property for opacity (with **qss** implementation) you can have an opacity animation.

Here is the example. `QLabel` subclass:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QLabel>

class OpacityLabel : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(float opacity READ opacity WRITE setOpacity)

public:
    explicit OpacityLabel(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    float opacity() const;
    void setOpacity(const float opacity);

private:
    float m_opacity = 1;
};
```

And cpp

```
#include "OpacityLabel.h"

OpacityLabel::OpacityLabel(QWidget *parent) : QLabel(parent)
{

}

float OpacityLabel::opacity() const
{
    return m_opacity;
}

void OpacityLabel::setOpacity(const float opacity)
{
    if (opacity > 1)
    {
        m_opacity = 1;
    }
    else if (opacity < 0)
    {
        m_opacity = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        m_opacity = opacity;
    }

    int opacityValue = m_opacity * 255; //css accepts values 0..255
    setStyleSheet(QString("QLabel{background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, %1); color: rgba(0, 0, 0, %1); }").arg(opacityValue));
}
```

And using like this (`ui->label` here is `OpacityLabel` not `QLabel`):

```
QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(ui->label, "opacity");
animation->setDuration(2000);
animation->setStartValue(0.1);
animation->setEndValue(1.0);
animation->start(QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
```

4. You can use `QGraphicsOpacityEffect` on your `QLabel` and animate effect instead of label.

For example, set effect:

```
QGraphicsOpacityEffect *effect = new QGraphicsOpacityEffect(ui->label_2);
ui->label_2->setGraphicsEffect(effect);
```

And then set animation

```
QPropertyAnimation *effectAnimation = new QPropertyAnimation(ui->label_2->graphicsEffect(), "opacity");
effectAnimation->setDuration(2000);
effectAnimation->setStartValue(0.1);
effectAnimation->setEndValue(1.0);
effectAnimation->start(QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
```